# Cannot launch app to Microsoft Emulator

Tags: xamarin.android

I've just installed VS2017 with Xamarin, including MS Emulator. When I create a new blank Android project I can see the drop down with about 6 emulators in it. The majority start with 'Visual Studio'. I assume they are the Microsoft Emulator? When I try to run I can see in the output it's going to the Google emulator and then it complains about turning Hyper-V off. I'm lost as to why it's not running the MS emulator. Any ideas?